# Mercer's theorem: Complex version

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, manifolds, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I really need the help of this forum on this one. My supervisor and I are in disagreement about how a complex version of Mercer's theorem should look like. Since we couldn't find any sources for the complex case, we are both a bit puzzled about how the other one arrived at their conclusion (hence a literature reference would also be crucial and appreciated). Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a nice enough manifold. His version is:

> Let
> $$Tf(\textbf{y}) := \int_{\mathcal{M}} K(\textbf{x},\textbf{y}) f(\textbf{x}) \, \mathrm{d} \mathbf{x}$$
> Suppose $K$ is a continuous symmetric (or hermitian) non-negative definite kernel. Then there is an orthonormal basis $\varphi_n(\mathbf x)$ of $L_2(\mathcal M)$ consisting of eigenfunctions of $TK$ such that the corresponding sequence of eigenvalues $\lambda_1\ge \lambda_2\ge \ldots>0$ is nonnegative. The eigenfunctions corresponding to non-zero eigenvalues are continuous on $\mathcal M$ and $K$ has the representation
> $$ 
>    K(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\lambda_{n}\,\varphi_{n}(x)\,
>    \overline{\varphi_{n}(y)}
> $$
> where the convergence is absolute and uniform with
> \begin{equation*}
> \lambda_n \varphi_n(y) =\int_{\mathcal M} K(x,y) \varphi_n(x) 
> \mathrm d x \, .
> \end{equation*}

My version is:

> Let
> $$Tf(\textbf{y}) := \int_{\mathcal{M}} K(\textbf{x},\textbf{y}) f(\textbf{x}) \, \mathrm{d} \mathbf{x}$$
> Suppose $K$ is a continuous symmetric (or hermitian) non-negative definite kernel. Then there is an orthonormal basis $\varphi_n(\mathbf x)$ of $L_2(\mathcal M)$ consisting of eigenfunctions of $TK$ such that the corresponding sequence of eigenvalues $\lambda_1\ge \lambda_2\ge \ldots>0$ is nonnegative. The eigenfunctions corresponding to non-zero eigenvalues are continuous on $\mathcal M$ and $K$ has the representation
> $$ 
>    K(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\lambda_{n}\,\color{red}{\overline{\varphi_{n}(x)}\, \varphi_{n}(y)}
> $$
> where the convergence is absolute and uniform with
> \begin{equation*}
> \lambda_n \varphi_n(y) =\int_{\mathcal M} \color{red}{K(x,y) \varphi_n(x)} 
> \mathrm d x \, .
> \end{equation*}

$\color{red}{\text{Expressions that were changed in response to the comments (conjugated to fit the proposed solution).}}$

He explains his solution as follows: Since the literature does not tell us explicitly about the complex case, we must assume that the complex case follows by almost exact analogy.

I explain my solution as follows: By assuming correctness of the stated theorem, we should be able to plug in a kernel $K$ with finite representation (i.e. finitely many non-zero eigenvalues) and show that the second equality for $\lambda_n \varphi_n(\mathbf{y})$ holds. I can even support this with numerical evidence from an algorithm that rests upon Mercer's theorem for this case -- but my supervisor wouldn't budge and I feel a bit icky trying to get behind his reasoning (barring obvious counterexamples)...

Thank you for any input on the matter!

Comment: I’m certainly not nearly as qualified as your advisor, but I think that “going from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ is just following the strictest analogy” is a dangerous strategy, especially given all these tricky complex conjugates. Back to your question: I suspect both versions are wrong. Your advisor’s formula doesn’t work because when you expand, you find that the RHS is proportional to some weird weighted combination of $\overline{\varphi_n(y)}$ (a problem that your formula solves). Yet their formula *has* to work because it’s simply $T\varphi_n=\lambda_n\varphi_n$. (Cont’d).

Comment: I think the problem is resolved when you realize that, in fact, $K(x,y)=\sum_n{\lambda_n\overline{\varphi_n(x)}\varphi_n(y)}$.

Comment: In particular, with *this* formula for $K(x,y)$ your approach should recover your advisor’s formula for $\lambda_n\varphi_n$.

Comment: @Aphelli Hm, you are right. I completly overlooked that the eigenfunctions of $T$ also need to be... well, eigenfunctions. I am not confident that it will convince him, but now that we have a *unique* representation sure feels nice. Is there anything else that you spotted in the statement?

Comment: @Aphelli If it is not asking too much: Can you point me to any references that might include a version of Mercer's theorem for hermitian Kernels?

Comment: I think under the constraint $T(\phi_n)(y) = \lambda_n \phi_n(y)$ and $T(\phi^*_n)(y) = \lambda_n \phi^*_n(y)$, both formulas have chances of being equally correct ? Interesting problem.

Comment: @TheOutZ i mentioned some comments as an answer. See if its useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are too much comments, posting this as an answer. I think its just about change of basis. $T,f,K(x,y)$ written in basis $\phi_n$ is your formula and $T,f,K(x,y)$ written in basis $\phi^*_n$ is your advisors formula. Having said that both formulas are equally correct under the constraint $T\phi_n = \lambda_n \phi_n$ and $T\phi_n^* = \lambda_n \phi_n^*$.

I am assuming orthonormal basis $\{\phi_n\}$ are orthonormal w.r.t $L_2$ inner product and not inner product w.r.t kernel.
If what your advisor said is correct, you will have the two equations i mentioned: $T\phi_n = \lambda_n \phi_n$ and $T\phi_n^* = \lambda_n \phi_n^*$. May be these 2 equations are your advisor's motivation.

These 2 conditions imply $T_{K-K^*}$ is a $0$ operator. This implies $K = K^*$. This implies $K$ is real.  May be this can be your argument.

Comment: Well, this boils down the question to if an $L^2(\mathcal{M})$ basis always includes it's conjugated complement. Is this always the case? If not, that would be a good counterexample (as otherwise your argument applies and we can't show anything).

Comment: If you assume the theorem your advisor says then $T\phi^* = \int  \sum_i \phi_i(x) \phi_i^*(y) \phi_n^*(x) dx $ assuming integral and summation can be swapped results in $\lambda_n \phi^*$, since $\int \phi_i(x) \phi_n^*(x) = \delta(i-n)$. So the only condition for the theorem suggested by your advisor to boil down to $K$ being real is if integral and summation can be swapped or not. Check this out and discuss with your advisor.

Comment: Since this obviously works in every case where $K$ is finitely representable, I think (cautiously) that there is very good reason that we can extend this to infinity by some limiting argument. If there is a weird counterexample to this (that isn't reasonable enough to appear in practice - else rather troublesome), I would be open to revise my opinion on this.

Comment: Hang on: Starting from my representation with the conjugation swapped, how do we arrive at the conclusion that $K$ is real? Am I just blind at the moment or doesn't this only imply that $\varphi_n$ is an eigenvalue to $T_K$ and $\overline{\varphi_n}$ is an eigenvalue to $T_{\overline{K}}$?

Comment: $K$ is real only from your advisor's version of the theorem (assuming integral and summation can be swapped). Further if your advisors eigen value equation is true then $\sum_i \lambda_i \phi_i^*(y) \int \phi_i(x)\phi_n(x) dx  = \lambda_n \phi_n$. If this equation is true then your theorem will also boil down to $T\phi_n^* = \lambda \phi_n^*$. Since $T\phi_n$ of ur advisors version and $T\phi_n^*$ of your version are conjugate of each other.

Comment: Hm okay, but how would you justify the comments given by @Aphelli then? If, by your argument, $K$ is real, then we could obtain my representation by conjugation. My representation does work for the stuff I talked about with Aphelli, but not for the equation of my advisor, though they must clearly be the same by your argument. How do your resolve this contradiction? Sorry for my confusion...

Comment: I am saying your advisors version implies $K$ is real but your version doesnt imply $K$ is real. If your advisors version is true then both yours and advisors version are equivalent which is equivalent to $T\phi_n = \lambda_n \phi_n$ and $T\phi^*_n = \lambda_n \phi^*_n$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140799/discussion-between-theoutz-and-balaji-sb).